# How to know at page load, if view state is clear at some other event on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a weird problem, i am dynamically loading user control at page load with ViewState condition check, if true then load it, else not.
Now the problem is on a dropdown selected index change event i set NULL to view state but the page load comes in action first and it sees that the viewstate is not null, so it load the control again, how to overcome with this problem, please let know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you load the user control at page PreRender event. This should resolve your issue. If not please give the page behind code.

Comment: see i have to persist the dynamicall added user control so at first i add the user control at run time on some selected index change of a frop down, and i set the viewstate, so at page load it see if the viewsate is not null then reload it.

Comment: Hello i made a call from the registering a prerender event and loading the user control there, but it calls for 3 times and write thrice on the page..what to do?

Comment: a quick solution could be using a bool variable isLoaded, before loading checking if its set, and while loading first time setting it.

Comment: yes i did the same, but then the control disappear, and it defeat the very purpose...what to do..please help me with this..

Comment: please refer the following URL same problem i posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306400/how-to-fix-the-dynamically-added-user-control-being-called-more-than-1-at-page-p

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean and save it in the viewstate? It's not pretty but neither is webforms. :)

Comment: Ahh now I get you, my bad. are you checking if it's a postback or not?